# Listening for desktop events Ubuntu MATE

Tags: gui, mate, events

Is there user-level access to desktop or window manager events in MATE? I'm thinking specifically of the 'change workspace' event, but I have a general interest also, so if there is a listener interface for GUI events I'd like to know about it.

I'm sure this exists at the system level i.e. in C or some other low level API, but perhaps someone has built one in Python or in some scripting language specific to the GUI application.